# ng-bootstrap modal uses default change detection -- is there away to enforce on push?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I have an angular app that enforces on push change detection or detach, depending on the component.  The app uses ng-bootstrap for a few components, namely modals.  While profiling the app, change detection cycles in the Angular profiler are showing gradually as expected as I interact with the app, but when an ng-bootstrap modal is launched, it appears to use the default change detection.

I have a screen cap video located [here](https://share.vidyard.com/watch/evCtQcRUzz6Q6W2jBLB9yw?).  Note the frame count in the bottom left corner of the screen: it increases rapidly after the modal is launched.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to enforce change detection strategy for the ng-bootstrap modal, or is this not possible?

Update: as it turns out, the rapid change detection was being caused by an incompatibility with Angular and a third-party devtools integration.  Removing the integration causes it to stop, but in this case it was exposing the issue of an ng-bootstrap modal having a different change detection strategy, so this question remains unresolved.